# Using excel Range Find and FindNext to iterate over a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am coming back to VBA after a long time away, and am trying to implement a loop to find multiple occurrences of a value. I have struggled a little, and trawled the net. I thine found this example;

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a50")
        Set c = .Find(2, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                c.Value = 99
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This comes from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) so I tended to assume that this would be a good example. I re-worked this to fit my application, and had an error. I then tried to run the example given by MSDN directly. I get the same error, shown below. This occurs on the line

```
Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKVX6.png)

Can anyone shed some light on this. I was really surprised that the MSDN example did not work.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd think it would, but they've never bothered to correct it. The problem is that you are removing all instances of 2 so c is eventually Nothing and the code is trying to check the address of Nothing (hence the error). You need only check whether c is Nothing.

By the way, you could use Find and Replace for this.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a50")
        Set c = .Find(2, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Do
                c.Value = 99
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are, of course, quite correct. This now works. Kind of obvious, now you look at it :-). Thanks

Comment: Worth being aware that the Range Find function will wrap-around, so you need to add your own mechanism to the loop to prevent this. Which is obviously what Microsoft were trying to do in their examp,e.